# Check if two integers has the same "ones digit"

Tags: c#, if-statement, int, digit

Say we have two values,

```
int a = 2489;
int b  = 3019201;
```

From these two values i want to create an if statement to check if the two values have the same ones digit. i.e. 248(9) and 301920(1). In this case they dont obviously.

But i want to make an if to check this, how would i go ahead and do this?

Comment: this seems like he is asking us to do his homework/assignment

Answer (score 3):

Check if the difference of `a` and `b` is divisible by 10 without remainder (modulo):

```
   bool hasSameOnes = (a - b) % 10 == 0
```

Comment: I thought there must be way to do it with division, but I failed to think of one :) Nice!

Answer (score 0):

Use the modulo operator:

```
if ( (a%10) == (b%10) )
{
}
```